# draw rectangle on Clicking Button with wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, button, wxpython

I am developing a test bench, in which on clicking a button, a specific test will be done, and accordingly if test is done successfully, then it should be indicated by colored rectangle. But the problem is that how can I bind 2 events with one button clicking event. And also when i execute the attached code, open clicking the button, rectangle wont show up on panel.

```
import wx



class MyClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, "GUI", size =(500,300))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        button=wx.Button(panel,label = 'Exit', pos = (250,180), size = (50,50))
        button1=wx.Button(panel,label = 'Open', pos = (50,50), size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,  self.Rectangle,button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.CloseButton,button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.CloseProgram)

    def Rectangle(self,e):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('RED'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('BLUE'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(130, 15, 90, 60)

    def CloseButton(self,e):
        self.Close(True)

    def CloseProgram(self,e):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=MyClass(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Firstly, self.panel in the function Rectangle does not exist. Secondly, you are binding your EVT_PAINT handler on button1 instead of the panel. If you want to draw the panel, you must bind its EVT_PAINT to it. If you bind it on the button1, you can only paint button1.

Comment: Also, I would recomment not messing about with the EVT_PAINT but using a widget, for example wx.Panel, and setting it's background color...